# selection of values by keys of json file using jackson

Tags: java, jackson

This is possibly the dumbest question on the entire site. I am new to Java and JSON and I need help. I am using API Jackson. The program receives a JSON file. From it I need to get:

1. List of people between the ages of 20 and 30, sorted by name
2. Unique list of cities;
3. The number of people with an age interval of 0-10, 11-20, 21-30 and so on.

At the moment I have learned how to translate a json file into a List java

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    try {
        List<Data> data = Arrays.asList(mapper.readValue(Paths.get("C:\\data.json").toFile(), Data[].class));


        System.out.println(data);


        } catch (JsonParseException jsonParseException) {
        jsonParseException.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JsonMappingException jsonMappingException) {
        jsonMappingException.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ioException) {
        ioException.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

A class was created to read the json file

```
public class Data {
    private int id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String dateOfBirth;
    private String city;


public Data(int id, String firstName, String lastName, String dateOfBirth, String city) {
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
        this.city = city;
    }

    public Data() {
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getDateOfBirth() {
        return dateOfBirth;
    }

    public void setDateOfBirth(String dateOfBirth) {
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[id = " + id + ", firstName = " + firstName + ", lastName = " + lastName + ", dateOfBirth = " + dateOfBirth + ", city = " + city + "]";
    }
}
```

Json file looks like this

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "firstName": "Lesley",
        "lastName": "Bryan",
        "dateOfBirth": "11/28/61",
        "city": "Southampton–Portsmouth"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "firstName": "Edward",
        "lastName": "Houston",
        "dateOfBirth": "10/5/92",
        "city": "Southampton–Portsmouth"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "firstName": "Donald",
        "lastName": "Ross",
        "dateOfBirth": "12/10/79",
        "city": "Glasgow"
    },
    {
        "id": "4",
        "firstName": "Peter",
        "lastName": "Kelly",
        "dateOfBirth": "3/17/04",
        "city": "Birmingham–Wolverhampton"
    },
    {
        "id": "5",
        "firstName": "Anthony",
        "lastName": "McKinney",
        "dateOfBirth": "3/6/68",
        "city": "Liverpool"
    },
    {
        "id": "6",
        "firstName": "David",
        "lastName": "Stewart",
        "dateOfBirth": "4/11/73",
        "city": "Leeds–Bradford"
    },
    {
        "id": "7",
        "firstName": "Christopher",
        "lastName": "Austin",
        "dateOfBirth": "12/28/74",
        "city": "Birmingham–Wolverhampton"
    },
    {
        "id": "8",
        "firstName": "Alvin",
        "lastName": "Hodge",
        "dateOfBirth": "11/25/58",
        "city": "Newcastle upon Tyne–Sunderland"
    },
    {
        "id": "9",
        "firstName": "Gerald",
        "lastName": "Higgins",
        "dateOfBirth": "6/28/55",
        "city": "Liverpool"
    },
    {
        "id": "10",
        "firstName": "Amos",
        "lastName": "Owens",
        "dateOfBirth": "1/16/01",
        "city": "Manchester-Salford"
    },
    {
        "id": "11",
        "firstName": "Christian",
        "lastName": "Bishop",
        "dateOfBirth": "11/14/50",
        "city": "Nottingham"
    },
    {
        "id": "12",
        "firstName": "Robert",
        "lastName": "Caldwell",
        "dateOfBirth": "12/8/80",
        "city": "Manchester-Salford"
    },
    {
        "id": "13",
        "firstName": "Brian",
        "lastName": "Heath",
        "dateOfBirth": "9/23/02",
        "city": "Newcastle upon Tyne–Sunderland"
    },
    {
        "id": "14",
        "firstName": "Mark",
        "lastName": "Anthony",
        "dateOfBirth": "1/8/92",
        "city": "London"
    },
    {
        "id": "15",
        "firstName": "Mark",
        "lastName": "Watson",
        "dateOfBirth": "7/27/91",
        "city": "Nottingham"
    },
    {
        "id": "16",
        "firstName": "Charles",
        "lastName": "Stafford",
        "dateOfBirth": "1/26/90",
        "city": "Birmingham–Wolverhampton"
    },
    {
        "id": "17",
        "firstName": "Steven",
        "lastName": "Merritt",
        "dateOfBirth": "12/4/63",
        "city": "Leeds–Bradford"
    },
    {
        "id": "18",
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": "Holmes",
        "dateOfBirth": "4/22/52",
        "city": "Southampton–Portsmouth"
    },
    {
        "id": "19",
        "firstName": "Mervin",
        "lastName": "Lewis",
        "dateOfBirth": "10/27/95",
        "city": "Birmingham–Wolverhampton"
    },
    {
        "id": "20",
        "firstName": "Peter",
        "lastName": "Marsh",
        "dateOfBirth": "12/10/63",
        "city": "Glasgow"
    },
    {
        "id": "21",
        "firstName": "Piers",
        "lastName": "Harrington",
        "dateOfBirth": "4/27/85",
        "city": "London"
    },
    {
        "id": "22",
        "firstName": "Matthew",
        "lastName": "O’Brien’",
        "dateOfBirth": "1/19/59",
        "city": "Manchester-Salford"
    }
]
```

Please tell me in what sequence of actions to complete the task. Once again I apologize for such a stupid message.
P.S.: All names, surnames and dates from the json file were obtained at random.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to update `Data` class to facilitate handling of ages and age groups:

1. Change type of `dateOfBirth` to `LocalDate`, update constructor/getter/provide custom setter to handle dates in the 20-th century
2. Add methods to get age in years and age group as String:
3. Update `toString` to print age

```java
class Data {
// ...
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "M/d/yy")
    private LocalDate dateOfBirth;

    public LocalDate getDateOfBirth() {
        return dateOfBirth;
    }

    public void setDateOfBirth(LocalDate dob) {
        if (dob.isAfter(LocalDate.now())) {
            dob = dob.minusYears(100);
        }
        this.dateOfBirth = dob;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public int getAge() {
        return Period.between(dateOfBirth, LocalDate.now()).getYears();
    }
        
    @JsonIgnore
    public String getAgeGroup() {
        int age = getAge();
        if (age < 11) {
            return "0..10";
        }
        return (age/10*10+1) + ".." + ((age/10 + 1) * 10);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "[id = " + id + ", age=" + getAge() + ", firstName = " + firstName + ", lastName = " + lastName + ", dateOfBirth = " + dateOfBirth + ", city = " + city + "]";
    }
}
```

Then you can get required subsets of data from the input list:

```java
// get people aged from 20 to 30 sorted by last name/first name
List<Data> age20to30 = data
        .stream()
        .filter(p -> p.getAge() >= 20 && p.getAge() < 30)
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(p -> p.getLastName() + " " + p.getFirstName()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
age20to30.forEach(System.out::println);

// get sorted list of unique cities (using TreeSet as a SortedSet)
Set<String> cities = data
        .stream()
        .map(Data::getCity)
        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new));
cities.forEach(System.out::println);

// get stats by age groups
Map<String, Long> byAges = data
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Data::getAgeGroup, TreeMap::new, Collectors.counting()));
System.out.println(byAges);
```

**Output**

```
[id = 14, age=28, firstName = Mark, lastName = Anthony, dateOfBirth = 1992-01-08, city = London]
[id = 2, age=27, firstName = Edward, lastName = Houston, dateOfBirth = 1992-10-05, city = Southampton–Portsmouth]
[id = 19, age=24, firstName = Mervin, lastName = Lewis, dateOfBirth = 1995-10-27, city = Birmingham–Wolverhampton]
[id = 15, age=29, firstName = Mark, lastName = Watson, dateOfBirth = 1991-07-27, city = Nottingham]

Birmingham–Wolverhampton
Glasgow
Leeds–Bradford
Liverpool
London
Manchester-Salford
Newcastle upon Tyne–Sunderland
Nottingham
Southampton–Portsmouth

{11..20=3, 21..30=4, 31..40=3, 41..50=3, 51..60=4, 61..70=5}
```

Comment: Cannot construct instance of `com.testsample.Data` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
 at [Source: (File); line: 3, column: 3] (through reference chain: java.lang.Object[][0])

Comment: There seems to be an issue with the structure of the JSON file. I double checked parsing of the data provided above as a string and within a file and it worked fine.